# Certificate VerifyNoRevocation() is returning false in Azure APIM - What is going on behind the scene?

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-api-management

I am using `API Management` service from `Microsoft Azure` and have below policy in place.

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null  || context.Request.Certificate.Issuer != "CN=MyCompany, OU=MyProject, O=MyOrganization, L=Daniel, S=IND, C=KAR" || context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter < DateTime.Now)">
      <return-response>
          <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
          <set-body template="none">Invalid client certificate</set-body>
      </return-response>
  </when>
</choose>
```

This works fine, however, when I add below piece to above code, it fails

```
 context.Request.Certificate.VerifyNoRevocation() != true
```

What actually happens? Does the certificate fail in revocation list?

**Error**

> MyCompany.Main.BusinessLogic.WebApiClients.ComparisonAsyncClient [(null)] - Data web API error. GetCustomerIds: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'; 403

**Question 1**

1. I have TWO certificate issuers who have the same `ROOT` certificate.
2. Issue araises only with one of the issuer!!

Does it mean, error is anything to do with Issuer?

**Question 2**

When the below line executed, which public certificate it is using from the APIM store? Because I have multiple certificates uploaded in the store.

```
      context.Request.Certificate.VerifyNoRevocation()
```

Comment: May I know the error message when the api fail ?

Comment: updated the error

Comment: Could you please enable `Negotiate client certificate` in your APIM. Go to your APIM, then `Custom domains` --> `Gateway` --> enable `Negotiate client certificate`. Please have a try.

Comment: If your APIM is Developer, Basic, Standard, or Premium tiers, try with the operations mentioned above. If your APIM is Consumption tier, try with enable `Request client certificate` in `Custom domains` tab.

Comment: Sure, Is there any article which explains the basics of certificates,  "Verify()" and "VerifyNoRevocation()" and also what does " Negotiate client certificate" actually means internally?

Comment: Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients).

Comment: I have updated a couple of important learnings in question. does it help ?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I mentioned in above comments ? I'm not sure if the solution can solve the problem, so please have a try first.

Comment: Yes, that step I have tried sometime last week and it did not help. in our prod environment "Negotiate client certificate" is unchecked since day 1 and application works without any issue.

Comment: Does it work when you remove the code `context.Request.Certificate.VerifyNoRevocation()` and also with multiple certificates in APIM store ?

Comment: Yes it works when I remove  context.Request.Certificate.VerifyNoRevocation() and also with multiple certificates in APIM store.

Comment: So I don't think multiple certificates is the cause of the problem.